# Parsing a really complicated nested json whose structure is always changing in JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a really complicated nested json whose structure is always changing. I want to parse it in JAVA such that I can retrieve any element using the key/field name.

Option 1 - The easiest way to do this would be to convert/parse the json into a JAVA object.
I have tried everything (gson, JSONObject, Jackson...) But I cant convert the json unless I have a java class ready and since the json doesn't follow a fixed structure I cant convert it into a JAVA class. Is there any other library that can convert the json to a java object? (Without the need for a pre existing java class to convert the json into)

Option 2 - Or is there a way/library I can use, which if given a portion of the json, the program prints all the elements in the json file. Something like this...

```
StreetAddressLine
PrimaryTownName : value
CountryISOAlpha2Code :value
TerritoryAbbreviatedName :value
PostalCode : value

{"PrimaryAddress": [        {
          "StreetAddressLine": [{"LineText": "492 Koller St"}],
          "PrimaryTownName": "San Francisco",
          "CountryISOAlpha2Code": "US",
          "TerritoryAbbreviatedName": "CA",
          "PostalCode": "94110",
          "AddressUsageTenureDetail": [{"TenureTypeText":           {
            "@DNBCodeValue": 1129,
            "$": "Rents"
          }}],
          "PremisesUsageDetail": [{"PremisesUsageFunctionDetail": [{"PremisesFunctionText":           {
            "@DNBCodeValue": 12058,
            "$": "Manufacturing"
          }}]}],
          "CountyOfficialName": "San Francisco County",
          "TerritoryOfficialName": "California",
          "CountryGroupName": "North America",
          "GeographicalPrecisionText":           {
            "@DNBCodeValue": 0,
            "$": "Unknown"
          },
          "UndeliverableIndicator": false,
          "MetropolitanStatisticalAreaUSCensusCode": ["San Francisco-Oakland-Hayward CA"],
          "RegisteredAddressIndicator": false,
          "ResidentialAddressIndicator": false
        }]}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the structure is always changing, a class wouldn't be appropriate. Even if you found a library to generate a class for you at runtime, you'd then be accessing it without knowing whether or not the elements existed.

If you can't fix the structure of the JSON then you should use a dynamic data structure like a tree.

Comment: you can actually use gson to get a Json object without knowing the class, by instead using [JsonParser's](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) `parse` method. It returns a generic `JsonElement`, which you could then iterate over in order to get the fields you want to do what you want.

Comment: @clearlyspam23 the problem with this approach is that I dont know the fields that are returned in the json, and without know the fields I cannot retrieve them from JsonElement

Comment: @Rohit if you know that the json returned is an object type, you can call the `JsonElement`'s `getAsJsonObject` method to get a [JsonObject](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html), then given that object, iterate over it's values using the `EntrySet` returned from `entrySet`. That should allow you to access the complete Json without needing to know any of the fields. What you do with those values is up to you.

Comment: @clearlyspam23 that sounds promising, Ill check it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution! I used the Jackson Parser

First map your jsonString to a JsonNode

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
```

Update the rootNode to contain the json for the required key:

```
    rootNode = rootNode.findParent(key);
```

and then depending on if it is an array or a list handle it seperately:

```
if(rootNode.path(key).isArray()){
//key is the field in the json that you might be looking for
for (final JsonNode objNode : rootNode) {

     for (Iterator<String> keyArray = objNode.getFieldNames(); keyArray.hasNext();){

         fieldName = keyArray.next();

         fieldValue = objNode.path(fieldName).asText();                 
         if(fieldValue != ""){
             System.out.println(fieldName + " = " + fieldValue);

         }else{
             arrayHandler(objNode,fieldName);
         }
     }
 }
```

At each iteration check if the resulting JsonNode is an array or a list.
If it is a List handle it differently (Just iterate over the key value pairs like this)

```
for (Iterator<String> keyArray = rootNode.getFieldNames(); keyArray.hasNext();){
        fieldName = keyArray.next();
        fieldValue = rootNode.get(fieldName).asText();
        System.out.println(fieldName + " = " + fieldValue);
    }
```

After every iteration check what the next jsonNode is and call the respective handler recursively...

Answer (score 3):

Try using [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse the JSON into a bunch of nested `JSONObject` (which basically  are maps) and `JSONArray` (which basically are lists) elements and extract the values yourself.

Just a node: `PrimaryAddress` indicates that there might be a `SecondaryAddress` as well, so the nesting should not change, otherwise it might be hard to determine things like which address `StreetAddressLine` belongs to.

In that case the better question would be: *why* does the structure change that often?

Comment: The json is a reply from a web service that is built by some company. The structure changes based on the information available. 
Thanks for your suggestion, I will check it out...